# google analytics api fails to return segment data

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use Google Analytics API to retrieve data for my custom segments.

They say here http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceAccountFeed.html#accountResponse that all the segments are listed in the account feed response.  But mine doesn't contain them.

Has anyone else had this problem and know a way to get the data out from them?

Thanks,

Beth

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add **GData-Version: 2** in your header.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't use this header you can't get/use any segments. Spent hours on it.